# Authorization failed when checkout

Tags: svn, configuration

I get an error when I want to checkout my SVN server. I use Turtoire on my Windows and the SVN server is based on linux.

svnserve.conf

```
[general]
anon-access = none
auth-access = write
password-db = passwd
authz-db = authz
realm = Project_ASI
```

passwd

```
[users]
red = v1z2r
dips = dipsi
```

authz

```
[groups]
red_and_dips = red,dips

[Project_ASI:/]
@red_and_dips = rw
```

This is what I'm get when I want to test it :

```
root@dm800:/media/hda1/svn/test# svn checkout svn://192.168.1.100/test test --us
ername red
Authentication realm: <svn://192.168.1.100:3690> Project_ASI
Password for 'red':

-----------------------------------------------------------------------
ATTENTION!  Your password for authentication realm:

   <svn://192.168.1.100:3690> Project_ASI

can only be stored to disk unencrypted!  You are advised to configure
your system so that Subversion can store passwords encrypted, if
possible.  See the documentation for details.

You can avoid future appearances of this warning by setting the value
of the 'store-plaintext-passwords' option to either 'yes' or 'no' in
'/home/root/.subversion/servers'.
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Store password unencrypted (yes/no)? yes
svn: Authorization failed
root@dm800:/media/hda1/svn/test#

You can avoid future appearances of this warning by setting the value
of the 'store-plaintext-passwords' option to either 'yes' or 'no' in
'/home/root/.subversion/servers'.
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Store password unencrypted (yes/no)? yes
svn: Authorization failed
```

What's is wrong with my configuration files ?

Comment: you write that you're using Tortoise but the stuff above looks like command line. That's a bit strange...

Answer (score 1):

First

authz

```
[groups]
red_and_dips = red,dips

[Project_ASI:/]
@red_and_dips = rw
```

add `* =` look like

```
[groups]
red_and_dips = red,dips

[Project_ASI:/]
@red_and_dips = rw
* =
```

Second

> Please show your path/of/repositories/

Let us investigate in further,thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error from server, at the end fixed it by writing the full path in file svnserve.conf.

```
[general]
anon-access = none
auth-access = write
## password-db = passwd
password-db = /path/to/repos/conf/passwd
## authz-db = authz
authz-db = /path/to/repos/conf/authz
```